# decrement switch statement output

Tags: java, switch-statement, decrement

basically the output says `i = 11`, though each time I try to trace it the answer comes up `9` with me.
I've been playing with the code a little to see where the extra 2 comes from. Its in the case `3/4`, but I can't find any increment state for `i` though it becomes `4` at that point. Can anyone help and explain this to me?

```
public class out2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0, j = 7;
        boolean f = true;
        while (i <= 4) {
            switch (--j) {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    i = f ? i + 7 : i + 1;
                    break;
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    i = !f ? j++ : j--;
                    break;
                case 5:
                case 6:
                    i = (i == j) ? i - 1 : i + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("j=" + j + "\ni=" + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug and see what the execution flow is by placing some break points?

Comment: Or even simpler: try to see the flow by adding a println into the while loop.

Comment: guys stop being mean that's how it's written in the bloody test paper so i need to understand it the way it is -_-

Comment: Here `i = !f ? j++ : j--` `j` is 4 and becomes 3, but before the decrement it is assigned to `i`, so `i` is 4. Next iteration is for `j=3` and `i=4`, and the switch adds 7 to `i` and decreases `j` by 1, thus `i=11` and `j=2`. I think you could get it by yourself, just grab a piece of paper and follow the code...

Comment: @zaidshawahin don't worry, it is a legitimate question. It is just hard to understand and difficult to see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepping through it with the debugger would show you that...

**Loop 1**

`--j` so `j` is decremented

`i = (i == j) ? i - 1 : i + 1;` = `i+1`

...so `i=1` (i=0 + 1) as `i` is not equal to `j`

**Loop 2**

`--j` = 5

`i = (i == j) ? i - 1 : i + 1;` = `i+1`

...so `i=2` (i=1 + 1) as `i` is not equal to `j`

**Loop 3**

`--j` = 4

`i = !f ? j++ : j--;` = `j--` = `i=j; j++` = `i=j; j=j-1`

...so `i=4` (i=j) & `j=3` (j=4 -1 which happens after the assignment to i) as `!f` is false

**Loop 4**

`--j` = 2

`i = f ? i + 7 : i + 1;` = `i+7`

...so `i=11` (i=4 + 7) & `j=2` as `f` is true

...how are you getting 9?

**Notes**

- testing `!true` is just saying is 'not true', true; which it isn't, of course.
- doing `i=j++` assigns `j` to `i` then increments `j`
- doing `i=++j` increments `j` then assigns to `i`
- doing `i = true ? j++ : j--` will assign `j` to `i` then increment `j` which is why you are getting 9 it looks like, @GameDroids spotted that you weren't assigning to `i`

Comment: I think OP is getting a `9` when trying to retrace it on paper – it's the i++ and i-- which is confusing

Comment: Yes but I can't see why they are getting 9 on paper, I can't get 9 even playing with pre and post assign increment and decrement

Comment: I rechecked it again, sorry it wasn't the `i++` or `i--`. The `9` is the result when in this `case` the value of `j` is not assigned to `i` (regardless of when j is incremented/decremented)

Comment: ah, you are right about the assignment, I'll include that

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the program for you, maybe that way it is easier to understand:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 7;
    boolean f = true;
    while (i <= 4) {
        switch (--j) {
            case 1:  // no break here
            case 2:
                //  i = f ? i + 7 : i + 1;
                // this you can rewrite to:
                if (f) {
                    i = i + 7;
                } else {
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                break;
            case 3:  // no break here
            case 4:
                // i = !f ? j++ : j--;
                // this you can rewrite to:
                if (!f) {
                    // if f == false
                    i=j; 
                    j++;
                } else {
                    // if f == true
                    i=j;
                    j--;
                }
                break;
            case 5:  // no break here
            case 6:
                //  i = (i == j) ? i - 1 : i + 1;
                // this you can rewrite to:
                if (i == j) {
                    i = i - 1;
                } else {
                    i = i + 1;
                }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("j=" + j + "\ni=" + i);
}
```

in more detail:

```
i = f ? i + 7 : i + 1;
```

here `i` gets a new value, which is `f ? i + 7 : i + 1`, so you need to evaluate that expression first: it checks if `f` is set to `true` if so, then that expression returns `i+7` otherwise it returns `i+1` (when `f` is set to `false`)

The other two expressions like this, can be rewritten the same way.
Now the trick is the second expression:

```
i = !f ? j++ : j--;
```

one would think that  first `j++` or `j--` will be evaluated, but that's not true. `i++` or `i--` means that **first** the current value of `i` will be used and **then** the value will be incremented/decremented. So: `i=j` **first** and then `j++` or `j--` **afterwards**

In your calculation (when you get `9` at the end) you just forgot to assign the value of `j` to `i`. You just calculated `j++` or `j--` but not `i=j` :)

On a side note: especially at the beginning you should try to stick to a clear coding style. Don't use *one-line* declarations like `int i=0, j=7`. It is hard to read and it can get confusing one day if you have more declarations in one line.. The second thing I would like to say is: classes should have a name with a capital letter `Out2` instead of `out2` :)